# Call an Action from Module.php

Tags: zend-framework2

I have an application that need a session refresh every 5 minutes.
I have the sessionRefreshAction in Auth Controller.
How I can call it through Module.php of Application.
I was thinking with forward()->dispatch() but I don't know how to do.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should probably create a class that you instantiate in both your controller and your Module.php that performs the common functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14138160/1699833)  this will solve your problem

```
// Redirect to the user login page, as an example
$router   = $e->getRouter();
$url      = $router->assemble(array(), array(
    'name' => 'zfcuser/sessionrefresh'
));

$response = $e->getResponse();
$response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Location', $url);
$response->setStatusCode(302);

return $response;
```