# Setting an authentication page using Zend2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I've developped a web-app using Zend 2, and now that I'm wondering to add to it an authentication page, I dont know if it's a good practice to set a connectionAction() into my IndexController with disabling the layout.

What's the recommanded way to proceed ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello, what did you tried so far?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14137868/zend-framework-2-global-check-for-authentication-with-zfcuser, answer available http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14137868/zend-framework-2-global-check-for-authentication-with-zfcuser/14138160#14138160?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of using a framework is to speed up development times. So, why don't you use a module like:

```
https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser
```

Follow installation steps, and then create a new module on your application like User, and start to override what is already on ZfcUser, in this way you will have your custom version without altering the library, so if the library updates you won't lost your customization:

```
http://www.codeforest.net/extending-zfcuser-zend-framework-2
```