# zf2 -I want to check hasIdentity() of user at once in controller not in every controller action

Tags: zend-framework2

I am new in ZendFramework2, need to check identity of user at once. Right now I am checking in every controller action (sample code in action for checking identity)

```
if (! $this->getServiceLocator()
                 ->get('AuthService')->hasIdentity()){
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('login');
}
```

this is not the good practice so help me to reduce to call once for all the action() method. Unauthorised user will redirect to login form

Thanks

Comment: Here is what you're looking for : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14138160/1386551

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a method that fires "on dispatch" to your controller:

```
class YourController extends AbstractActionController {

public function onDispatch($event){
    $this->yourIdentityCheckFunction();
    return parent::onDispatch($event);
}
//your other actions/identityCheck methods etc...
```

}